# Google Maps Distance Matrix API Rounding JS API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, distance

i have a problem like i mentioned at title. Please look at images at bottom first.
[image: 130 METERS]

In this image you can easily see it's 130 meters but if i use Distance Matrix API it's showing 0.1 KM,

[image: 180 METERS]

And here it's 180 Meters but it's showing 0.2 KM in distance matrix API. It's both google how can it be different..

And here's my code to get distance :

```
 var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
      {
          origins: startArray, //LatLng Array
          destinations: finishArray, //LatLng Array
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false
      }, callback);

function callback(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
        var origins = response.originAddresses;
        var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

        for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
            var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                console.log(results[i].distance.text);
                document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_hidSpeed').value += results[i].distance.text+"&";
        }
}
}
```

**Any help would be appreciated**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `results[i].distance.value` instead of the `text`.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_responses for an example, in text, it's rounded, but the value displays the distance accurately in meters.

Answer (score 0):

Figure I'd post this in case it may help someone in the future. If you'd like to show either km or m:

```
var distance = results[i].distance.value
if (distance < 1000){
    distance = results[i].distance.value + ' m';                    
} else {
    distance = results[i].distance.text;
}
```